# Where is KeyEventTranslations.tr in Mathematica 9?

Tags: front-end

I can't find the file in it's usual place /Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/... was it removed?

Comment: In version 7 mine in here: `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", 
   "Windows", "KeyEventTranslations.tr"}] // FilePrint`  I have also made a working copy to the matching path under the `$UserBaseDirectory`.

Comment: I guess that's in OSX right? Probably you should clarify that somewhere. Also, isn't it maybe in the `.app` bundle? (It's been a while since I used Mathematica under OSX)

Comment: in OS X it is currently in the directory: `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "TextResources", "Macintosh"}]`

Comment: In Ubuntu it is in the directory: `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "X"}]`

Answer (score 7):

You may have copied it to `/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/` yourself for your previous installation, and forgotten about it, as that is not the default location of this file.

It is found in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFile/FrontEnd/TextResources/name-of-your-os/` both in version 9 and earlier.  On OS X the installation directory is the app bundle.  To access it in the finder, you need to right click Mathematica.app and choose Show Package Contents.

Comment: Was the edit before or after my comment? Or in other words: Was I really to stupid to read? :)

Comment: @sebhofer It was *because of* your comment.